# Django How to retrieve datetime object with timezone from database

Tags: python, django, datetime

I am having a difficult time with all the mumbo-jungo timezone UTC thing in python.  In a django form, I create a zumba class(zumba app for a friend) and select a name, and date and time that the class will happen on.  Say I create the class for September 19, 8pm, and I am in the America/New York zone, so -4h.  In the Posgres database, the entry will be `2019-09-20 00:00:00+00`

Django shows the date and time correctly in the view, but when I retrieve the date object afterwards in the code, I always get as if the class is happening on the 20th at midnight.  The timezone offset is not taken into account.  Here is the database request to retrieve the zumbaclass object.

```
this_class = zumbaClass.objects.get(id=class_id)
```

if I do

```
print(this_class.date.date())
```

I get `2019-09-20 00:00:00+00:00`

Is there a way to get the time taking the timezone into account correctly?

EDIT:  Some more details, Django is configured to be timezone aware(USE_TZ = True and Timezone is defined)

Comment: Do you just want to convert it into the `TIME_ZONE` timezone, or should the timezone be specific to each event (or user, or whatever)?

Comment: Yes, I want to retrieve the original time, so with the timezone set in the Timezone setting

Comment: By searching through various posts I found this method, but it looks like it's a bit too complicated to be "pythonic"  `print(this_class.date.astimezone(pytz.timezone('America/Toronto')))`

Comment: Use [`localtime()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.localtime).